# Running docker containers in jenkins docker agent

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins

I've just started working with Jenkins and got stub into a problem of this kind: my nodejs application need to start it's own docker containers (with mongodb) in order to perform tests. I was doing it nicely on my local  machine, but now I'm not sure how to make it work in jenkins.

my Jenkins is a standalone setup (not containerized)

it runs the pipeline with help of docker agent

So actually the task is to run docker inside docker, which doesn't seem to be difficult, but it doesn't work, even though I've mounted docker socker and docker run file in the args..

With this setup jenkins can't start the agent container

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'danthedev/dtd-docker-node'
      args '-p 3000:3000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):$(which docker)'
    }
  }

  environment {
    CI = 'true'
  }


  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'yarn install'
      }
    }

    stage('Test') {
      environment {
        NODE_ENV = 'test'
      }
      steps {
        sh 'yarn test'
      }
    }

  }
}
```

/////

```
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 122:131 -p 3000:3000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):$(which docker) -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ypc -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ypc:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ypc:rw,z -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ypc@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ypc@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** --entrypoint cat danthedev/dtd-docker-node
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'danthedev/dtd-docker-node'. Error: docker: invalid reference format.
```

---

UPD.
I've changed docker args to 
`args '-p 3000:3000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker'`

now the error is `Error: connect EACCES /var/run/docker.sock`

So it's a matter of setting right access rights now..

Comment: Sorry this question might not be relevant, but why are you trying to run docker inside docker in the first place? Isn't it a better approach to run the test docker image outside the docker  container?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for reply. You mean I shouldn't use `agent { docker }` for this operation? I'm doing this because it was on the tutorial mainly, but actually otherwise I'll have to install at least  nodejs and yarn on the server where jenkins runs, which is not that difficult of course, but it seems cleaner not to do that, because the current server is a quite temporary one and it's nice not to have any dependencies. Of course I could build a docker container of `jenkins + node + yarn' but then again it will be docker-inside-docker. Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: You can create a test docker image, upload it to a local Docker hub (Amazon ECR may be), run a docker-compose file on the host machine which will run the latest docker test image on the host. 

This way, all the dependencies will be on the test docker image. Host will only to have Docker installed.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll follow your advice!

Comment: But I will still have to run docker inside docker, because my tests spawn docker containers themselves

Comment: You can run another docker container from one docker container using host docker daemon. You have to use something like:

`docker run -it --user root
-p 80:8080 
-v jenkins-home:/var/jenkins_home
-v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker`

You can use **docker-compose** in same way too.